# Kotlin - "in" keyword - what is is used for?

Tags: kotlin

i am trying to understand when to use the "in" keyword in generics as opposed to the "out" keyword (which allows assigning to subclasses).

I am actually following this [tutorial](http://www.baeldung.com/kotlin-generics) if it matters.

Lets say we have the following class defintiion:

```
class ParameterizedConsumer<in T> {
    fun toString(value: T): String {
        return value.toString()
    }
}
```

How does this even compile since value is not guaranteed to be a String ? is this what the in keyword does ? it tells the class that there is a guarantee the type wont be any other subclass ?  I am just not clear on the usecase for it, can you help ?

the tutorial says i will be able to call the following but i am lost as to what it has changed:

```
 val parameterizedConsumer = ParameterizedConsumer<Number>()

val ref: ParameterizedConsumer<Double> = parameterizedConsumer

assertTrue(ref is ParameterizedConsumer<Double>)
```

UPDATE: I get it now.  Out means you can downcast when producing. and "In" means you can downcast when assigning.

So in java this is not allowed:

```
// Java
void demo(Source<String> strs) {
  Source<Object> objects = strs; // !!! Not allowed in Java
  // ...
}
```

but in kotlin we can fix that if we use the "out" keyword we can assign to a downcasted class (subclass). likewise with "in" we can pass in a subclass into the class internally to use but not outwardly.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

> it tells the class that there is a guarantee the type wont be any other subclass ? I am just not clear on the usecase for it, can you help ?

Say you have a function that wants to add some items to a list you supply. The items are of type `Int`.

Question: what kinds of list are acceptable to this function?

Answer: `MutableList<Int>`, `MutableList<Number>`, `MutableList<Any>`. Or, in short, `MutableList<in Int>`.

---

In the same spirit, let's explain the `out` projection.

Say you have a function that wants to get some elements from a list you supply. The items are of type `Future`.

Question: what kinds of list are acceptable to this function?

Answer: `List<Future>`, `List<RunnableFuture>`, `List<ScheduledFuture>`... or, in short, `List<out Future>`.

Comment: can you also provide an example using "out". the example with in was very good but i want to see the difference.

Answer (score 1):

I'll answer part of your question

> How does this even compile since value is not guaranteed to be a String

So what? You can call `.toString()` on any type. That's how you get a string you'll be returning.

Comment: i see, toString() is apart of Any object. i see that part now.

Comment: @j2emanue: as for your other question, try this: https://kotlinlang.org/docs/reference/generics.html. It's called covariance/contravariance.